# nHibernate query exception: no row with given identifier exists

Tags: nhibernate

After modifying the datamodel a little bit, certain queries started giving me this exception. However, even after reading various forum-threads and blogs, I don't understand why this happens in my case. So I hope that someone here can help. First, an example query:

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SomeEntity));
        criteria.Add(Expression.IdEq(id));
        criteria.SetFetchMode("_PrivateProperty", FetchMode.Eager);
        criteria.CreateAlias("PublicProperty", "alias");
        criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("alias.Id", aliasId));
```

If I modify the query by either removing (1) SetFetchMode or (2) CreateAlias for the public property, everything works fine.

The private property is usually loaded lazily, but in this case I want to load it together with its parent entity to combat select N+1.

So, why doesn't it work as displayed above, and does it work when I remove certain parts of the query?

**UPDATE**

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeEntity this_ 
inner join PublicProperty alias4_ on this_.SomeEntityId=alias4_.SomeEntityId 
inner join ReferencedProperty rp2_ on alias4_.RPId=rp2_.RPId 
left outer join PrivateProperty v1_ on this_.SomeEntityId=v1_.SomeEntityId 
WHERE this_.SomeEntityId= @p0 and rp2_.RPId= @p1
```

When run in SQL Server Management Studio, it works as expected. I get two results. In between modifying the datamodel and the query, the data in the database hasn't changed.

**UPDATE2**

Modification in model.
Original mapping:

```
References(d => d.PublicProperty, "PublicPropertyId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

New mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(d => d.PublicPropertys)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Table("SomeEntityPublicProperty")
            .ParentKeyColumn("SomeEntityId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("PublicPropertyId")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Inverse();
```

**UPDATE3**

```
HasMany<PrivatePropertyEntity>(Reveal.Member<SomeEntity>("_PrivateProperty"))
            .Table("SomeEntity_PrivateProperty")
            .KeyColumn("SomeEntityId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .LazyLoad().Inverse();
```

Comment: how does the generated SQL looks like?

Comment: You never told us what you changed about the data model. Was it something related to the id datatype?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I modified `PublicProperty` from one-to-one to many-to-many (i.e. References -> HasManyToMany in Fluent). The property used to be a foreign key defined in `SomeEntity`, but now I have an additional table containing the relations between the two.

Comment: What the name of the mapping table used with PublicProperty table?

Comment: Is _PrivateProperty really a property, or a field ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem likely stems from the fact that if you use createalias (without specifying an outer join type) the entities don't get loaded eagerly in spite of what your configuration is.

The reason for this related to your error:  Assuming you didn't specify any criteria on the RHS of the association, and you have null references in your data, using an INNER JOIN would incorrectly filter out records on the LHS.

As such, it doesn't matter to NHibernate that your query returns two results using the INNER JOINS it goes ahead and lazy loads the associations anyway.  Somewhere you have a reference to a non-existent referenced property in your many-to-many join table, and it is failing when it tries to lazy load it to check whether the RHS matches you criteria.

Changing the alias to perform a left outer join *should* prevent the error (it will actually load the associated entities eagerly and not re-check the references), but you'll still have that referential integrity problem somewhere:

```
criteria.CreateAlias("PublicProperty", "alias", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

Comment: mootinator, I've checked but every entity has an associated publicproperty. This is expected as they used to be in the table of someentity in a non-null column. Changing to LeftOuterJoin didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem wouldn't be an entity without a PublicProperty, it would be a record in `SomeEntityPublicProperty` having an invalid reference to `PublicProperty`.  Have you checked for that (change the generated SQL to use outer joins and use only `WHERE this_.SomeEntityId= @p0` in the condition.

Comment: Have you tried the usual method of suppressing this error?  i.e. adding `.NotFound.Ignore()` to your `ManyToMany` mapping?

Comment: I've checked and checked again, but every row has a matching row in the other table. So not surprisingly these changes didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Are you not dealing with three tables now?  `SomeEntity` `SomeEntityPublicProperty` and `PublicProperty` Which one is "the other table".  The whole idea of your change was changing the relationship from many to one to many to many no?

Comment: All three tables are fully linked to each other (if that's the correct way to put it). Every item in `SomeEntityPublicProperty` has a matching entity in the other two tables.

Comment: Final suggestion then:  Get the 30 day trial of the NHibernate Profiler, and use it to determine exactly what query it's choking on.  http://nhprof.com/  *Well* worth the money to buy too if you do any amount NHibernate development consistently.

Comment: Well, it's the only option I have left I guess. Thanks for your effort. I'll make sure to post what was wrong when I find it.